# Some questions about a single ended system and common mode noise

Tags: common-mode, single-ended

Below is a system where a signal source on the left is floating/ungrounded/unearthed and the measurement system on the right is earth-grounded through the signal analog ground AGND:

[image]

Regarding the above setup I have the following questions:

1. Is there still change for a ground loop to occur through earth coupling?
2. If there would be earth coupling through parasitic capacitance, would that be a type of common mode noise?(Would that couple to both AGND and signal line?)
3. I see always one side recommended to be earth-grounded. What would be the disadvantage of making both signal and measurement sides unearthed?

Comment: Depends what noise is nearby and and how the two grounds are connected to signal and noise.  No answer possible with limited info. You want low CM impedance load to shunt CM noise.

Answer (score 2):

1. No ground loop.  That comes from having multiple ground connections forming a literal loop, and you don't have that.  If the source's case were also connected to AGND, then it would be a loop.
2. There is always both capacitive and inductive coupling:

   - Capacitive applies to the entire wire as a unit and follows nearby voltages
   - Inductive goes from one end of a wire to the other and follows nearby currents

   A low-impedance path to somewhere* typically overrides capacitive coupling to the point that you don't care anymore, but it does nothing for inductive coupling.  So far, you've solved half of the problem for one of the two wires.  The other wire may or may not be okay, depending on the output impedance of the sensor.

   Inductive coupling makes the sensor's ground "wiggle", so its output also follows that "wiggle", and then adds the opposite "wiggle" to the signal return wire.  So you'd think the "wiggles" would cancel, but only if the wires were to exactly coincide, which they obviously don't...unless you use coax.

   * "Somewhere" is usually an AC ground, which could be the circuit reference or anything else that can hold a steady DC value.
3. If you leave the sensor completely floating, then the common-mode voltage becomes uncontrolled.  It'll pick up *lots* of noise from everywhere and probably run into the input protection diodes.  These built-in diodes are there for a variety of good reasons, but they also create their own noise as they switch.  Plus, you're relying on the Common-Mode Rejection Ratio (CMRR) of your input stage to take that noise back out, which also isn't perfect.

---

### A better idea:

Take a cue from professional audio and use a shielded twisted pair (STP) to carry a balanced signal.  This arrangement done right will carry a microphone-level signal unamplified from stage to a mid-audience or balcony sound booth while keeping the noise inaudible:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzovjX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The upper one appears to be what you're doing, and is exactly how it ends up for a typical hand-held microphone.

- The grounded shield takes care of capacitive coupling, and you'll notice that it remains a shield/case and does not connect to the sensor itself.
- Now both wires are used as inputs, one subtracted from the other to take out whatever capacitive coupling might be left.  (the shield does pick up some at the far end because of its finite impedance, and this couples again onto the signal wires)
- The common-mode voltage is set by R1/R2.  Their value of 6.8k is standard for pro audio, but you can use whatever you like as long as they're equal.
- The twisted pair puts both wires as close as possible to the same position so that the inductive coupling can cancel.
- The supply voltage is pretty standard for lots of analog electronics, not just audio.  Again, you can adjust as needed, as long as the Common Mode Voltage + Signal + Coupled Noise never exceeds the Input Amp's ratings.

The lower one is included for completeness, showing how a sensor can be powered through the same set of wires.

- You'll notice that the sensor only drives one signal wire, but the other has an equal resistor to ground.  The important thing to remember is to keep the impedances equal so that both types of coupling affect them equally.

Comment: Is the second answer yes or no? Is it common mode? Im asking because common mode noise cannot be filtered with LPF one needs chokes ect.

Comment: And how can I learn these step by step? I know ac theory passive circuits. Is this topic covered under signal integrity? The examples in net either too primitive short or too expert.

Comment: Common mode noise is mostly dealt with by using balanced signals.  Chokes can help too, but they're far more effective for radio frequencies than the audio that I deal with.  (That said though, RF can mess with audio inputs too, sometimes accidentally picking up a random AM broadcast station.)

Comment: I think it would help to put the terminology aside and think about what actually happens.  Try to simulate it in your head, perhaps using dots that flow along the lines to represent current and maybe a 3rd dimension into or out of the page for voltage.

Comment: Im just wondering in a single ended system like my example with coax cables can there be common mode noise? Would the earth suck up the noise hitting on AGND? Can you draw this signal example ?

Comment: If you can explain in  a simpler fashion I might understand thank you

Comment: Or for a mechanical analogy, instead of the usual plumbing one: voltage sources become anchors at rigid physical positions, resistors become springs, capacitors become shock absorbers, and inductors become inertia.  I find that this one actually works a lot better to understand signals anyway.  Capacitive coupling then becomes a push/pull rod from one system to another (with a loose spring in it), and inductive might be something like friction from two systems rubbing (except that this friction somehow works without even touching).

Comment: Like all analogies, it has to break down somewhere, but it can still be useful.

Comment: I think I couldn't express what Im asking about. I still dont get answer to my question even I appreciate your help. When noise hits, will there be voltage induced on AGND or will it be zero with respect to earth? And if the noise will only be induced on signal line but not AGND then does that mean thsi can be filtered by a LPF? Maybe if just draw an example noise induced on signal line and AGND in time domain that would help me. Something like this fashion showing signals in time on the lines: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e7/DiffSignaling.png/1200px-DiffSignaling.png

Comment: It all depends on impedance.  That diagram is completely misleading.  Not necessarily wrong, but misleading.  It focuses entirely on signals that hardly matter at all, and none on impedance that makes all the difference.  For example, my phantom-powered sensor that only drives one line but gives equal impedance to both could easily perform better than a complementary-driven line as per the wiki that doesn't give a moment's thought toward impedance.

Comment: The signals Im dealing are maximum 10Hz they are like DC analog signals like humidity sensor single ended output transducers coupled to ADC by coax cables.

Comment: Basically, higher impedance picks up more noise.  If one is tied to a "hard" ground, then that's about as low impedance as you can get, but still not zero outside of a cryogenic freezer.  If the other is driven by a finite-impedance sensor...well, let's see if you can figure out the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Consider 2 real scenarios for CM noise.

a)
The common mode DM,  noise current  much higher current than the differential mode DM input voltage signal into a high impedance differential load with high CMRR.

Lets say the signal is 10mV into 1M sgl, or 2M differential on 200 Ohm pairs unshielded. Nearby there is a stepper motor wire conducting 1A with RF noise from 50kHz commutation such that there is a mutual coupling of only 1%.

What noise output do you expect? How do you fix it?

Shielded pair wire?  CM Choke good for 50kHz and up?   single ended LPF?

b) Let's say the grounds are floating , you have the same signal and receiver and unshielded twisted pairs with a differential noise between grounds of 50V from floating at one end.

How do you fix it ? if we assume that connecting the grounds induces a common mode current noise of 10uA or 10uA*1M = 10V swamping your 10mV signal.

### Common solutions

- twisted pairs (UTP) for every voltage signal and every source of EMI current out.

  - shielded twisted pairs (STP) for above
  - active guarded CM signal driving shield of twisted pairs for signal below 1mV
  - impedance loaded signals with twin loads and better shunts to stray noise with Z matched lines. e.g. 600 Ohms , 50 ohms
- balun or CM Choke rated for frequency of interference. to raise CM impedance relative well above DM impedance.
- if you know remote earth ground has noise relative to local ground at line frequency then do not connected remote ground with 0 ohms but use 1~10nF instead for RF shunt. This avoids line f ground loops but reduces RF differences to CM noise but if not a differential input adds to noise for single ended inputs.
- use balanced differential amplifier , preferably INstrument Amp (INA) with high CMRR over interference spectrum , not good enough for RF

Comment: Signals Im dealing are maximum 10Hz they are like DC analog signals like humidity sensor single ended output transducers coupled to ADC by coax cables. Are your suggestions for RF engineering or covers low freq transducers as well?

Comment: DO you have any noise issues? do you know how to measure SNR noise?

Comment: Different types(I solved the ground loop) but recently I was told that sometimes a broadband noise appears during data acquisition for a short period and disappears. I was thinking maybe a device is switched on some other part of the building or nearby and maybe from earth or AC lines the analog signal is exposed to this noise. In my single ended example in my question, the system is exactly like that. My problem is the noise is not continuously existing and they say it appears only sometimes and for me hard to track. I was wondering what could be possible sources.

Comment: I thought if I cannot find the source of the noise at least I might use a filter method but Im not sure LPF would work if it is common mode noise.

Comment: Yes I can measure SNR in MATLAB

Comment: I mean real world SNR noise that is near stepper motors, pumps and triac controlled power loads with long cables of unknown impedance and inbalance.

Comment: Oh ok I dont have experience with measuring that.

Comment: that's what you need to do is try it near noisy relays coil wires or contact surges and try solutions in other question that I wrote.