# A question regarding noise investigation

Tags: noise

There is a single-ended earth grounded data acquisition system which is multiplexing and sampling eight channels at 500Hz sampling rate. Channel are isolated from earth ground and the signals are low freq. signals like force transducer amplifiers, temperature sensors ect.

After solving the 50Hz ground loop issues and be sure no ground loop exists, now sometimes(we don't know when and why) I'm encountering a large noise on all the channels. To make it more clear the two plot below are from the same transducer at different days(offset is expected but not the noise):

[image]

As you see above, the standard-deviation and the noise margin around the blue plot is much much greater than the green one. An this large white-like noise exists on all channels when it appears.

Here is the FFT spectrum of the noisy channel:

[image]

Before I investigate these, I dont have so much time and I'm not sure about some basic route paths I might follow.

1-) Can this be common mode noise? I'm asking because normally common mode noise is at 50/60hz by magnetic coupling. Because it seems to me(?), if the noise would be coming from a single transducer it would not appear on all the channels.

2-) Should this noise be considered as "white-noise" or can it be a particular high freq. noise?(The sampling rate is 500Hz).

3-) I'm planning to check or renew all the BNC connectors and coax cables. That's all I can think for now. Because people I work with don't want me to use any sort of filter. So I want to find the source of this noise. One of my colleague who is not into these subjects keeps saying the issue might be related to earth ground and want me to earth the transducer's frame. But that doesn't make sense to me. I'm really confused at this point. What kind of test or procedure should I follow? I don't know if the source of the noise is the ADC itself, or one of the signal input, or cables, or common-mode noise or the earth ground...

**edit:**

Another example of same issue when 16 channels sampled. ch14 and ch15 are analog output but still sampled:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that it is a communications problem?  I know that you can generate a signal like that by splitting 16 bit data on the wrong byte.  I've had similar happen when sampling audio on a PC.  The library I was using returned a bunch of bytes for each stereo 16 bit sample.  Due to an off by 1 error, my program was reading 8 bits from one sample and 8 bits from another.  The result was an awful racket that resembled your fft.

Comment: If you can catch while it is producing bad data, hook up an oscilloscope and see if it is real noise or a figment of the sampling system's imagination.

Comment: How are the signals being sourced?  Powered buffers with low-impedance outputs?  How are the sensors powered, cabled, and grounded with respect to the daq system?  Ground issues, with emi mixed in, are a real beast to handle.  The less-patient among us will default to grounding everything, and often, with dubious results.  You're right to explore the issue.  It doesn't help your cause to be using a single-ended, non-referenced daq.  Consider placing the  single-ended outputs on a differential daq input, with each sensor providing a ground to the separate daq '-' channels. 'pseudo-differential'

Comment: (cont) Remember that a dedicated return path for each signal is also important.  Terminating the signal at the daq input may help.  Also, are you controlling the scan speed of the daq mux?  Switching the mux too fast (not allowing enough 'settling time') can produce noisy signals via charge injection.  This is very common, and the solution is to switch the mux setting, allow the signal to settle, then sample the signal.  Good luck.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen The noise appears some times. No I didn't play with the settling time of the mux. Everything is single ended all the transducers isolated; only the adc is earth grounded. Does reducing the sampling rate help if I cannot lower the settling time? here is the adc in use: http://www.mccdaq.com/pdfs/manuals/PCI-DAS6034-35-36.pdf

Comment: @JRE Your argument makes sense, but I would assume a more crazy plot than this if the 8 bits of each 16bit is corrupted by that 8bit shift.

Comment: @doncarlos Please describe the connections.  'Single-ended' and 'isolated' rarely appear in the same sentence without confusion.  Schematic needed, showing the power connections, sensor part #'s, and output connections to the daq.

Comment: @doncarlos Mux-switching: most often mux switching noise will be constant.  However, it can be (mostly-is) a function of the voltage difference on adjacent mux channels.  So, neighboring channels with similar voltages will exhibit less 'pops'.  Slowing the sample rate will normally increase the settling time (good).  However, in reality that type of relationship is up to the daq designer and firmware author.  They really blew-it if that is the case (this is unlikely).

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen Connections are like in this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLWh0.gif only measurement side is earthed

Comment: I suspect RF interference being detected as DC offset by the amp's input stage. Does the board have proper lowpass filtering of inputs with low-inductance capacitors to ground?

Comment: @peufeu No anti-aliasing filters, no low pass filters. I suggested but they dont want to use because thay say: "the noise wasnt there before, why it is now and sometimes?" so they just want to find and remove the source of the noise. they think it will effect their measurements if i use filter or buffer ect. i couldn't convince about using LP filters.

Comment: No filters? WTF? Put your cellphone near the wires and make a call, check if noise appears in measurements. You might be surprised!

Comment: You mean near ADC or cables? The cables are coax are you sure I would see a result. That would be great if I can see that affect, that way I can convince them.

Comment: Try to move your phone around everywhere along the cables, sensors, etc while it is transmitting (like call your voice mail or something). Of course you can use any other RF transmitter, explore other frequencies but... you have a phone. This is similar to the loudspeakers making "zzzt-zzt-zt-zt-" when a cellphone transmits nearby. Input stage of opamps is 2 BJTs which are also 2 diodes. This makes a nice RF detector, which detects the power envelope of the RF signal. Thus varying RF levels add varying DC offsets.

Comment: I'm betting on maximum interference on the sensor end since the cable is not connected to the sensor shield, btw.

Comment: @peufeu "This makes a nice RF detector, which detects the power envelope of the RF signal" Is this similar to the way how crystal radio demodulates the RF by a diode? I will call someone and bring the cell phone to nearby to each transducer tomorrow. I hope I get some results.

Comment: Yes, this works the same as a diode demodulator. Anything that is non-linear will demodulate RF... a diode, or even a rusty bolt or a bad contact! If this is the problem (it is only a hypothesis for now but it would explain the intermittent nature of the noise) then the fix is a lowpass filter. Since your bandwidth seems to be in the low Hertz, a lowpass at 100kHz should be completely unnoticeable in the measurements. But the lowpass needs to work at GHz frequencies, so the layout must be good. Anyway, do the test and we'll see.

Comment: @peufeu Btw DC offset in the plots is not about noise, that is just a shift due to sensor output which is normal. Noise is the white-like noise the deviation around the mean. And this noise appears in "all channels". I just wanted to indicate in case .. If RF hits on a single channel how can it appear on all channels I dont get it anyway.

Comment: Varying amounts of RF will result in varying DC offset vs time (ie, random time-varying crap added to your signal). If it appears in all channels with absolutely identical amplitudes, then RF is less likely, and software bug more likely ;) but no harm in testing...

Comment: Another example of the same issue with 16 channels sampled(ch14 and ch15 are analog output but still sampled). see my edit or : https://i.stack.imgur.com/exIpA.png whitelike noise appears at all channels

Comment: Hmm, if all channels are equally affected then RF is less likely (unless the ADC is muxed and the RF gets in and acts after the mux maybe). Could you post a block diagram of your acquisition chain?

Comment: @doncarlos  Even the (small) picture you linked is not clear enough (i.stack.imgur.com/SLWh0.gif).  Is the (-) terminal programmed to be connected to the DAQ ground or is it connected to a diff-amp (-) input?  If the isolated (-) output is not connected to a ground ref (or biased by a low impedance source), then your signals are *floating* and you will see nastiness as the CMV flops all over the place.  Connect the isolated (-) output of your sensor to your daq ground reference with an additional wire and see how that channel performs.  _Typically_ A2D inputs on DAQ cards can't be floating.

Comment: I assume that this is a followup to [your previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/329548/11683).This is exactly why we discourage broad, open-ended questions relating to the reverse engineering and/or repair of devices here on EE.SE: The answer(s) tend to become long strings of unrelated edits and/or comments. While this might help you with your immediate problems, it is of no value to the site overall.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen It is single ended earth grounded system. The connections are exactly how you suggest. The isolated outputs' (-) ends(signal grounds) are all connected together at the receiver ground and from there they are tied to the earth through PC's motherboard. Im tired of these spikes causing high deviations and ringing issues. And the noise is big sometimes sometimes not. I guess the 16 coaxial signal channels with different output impedances to the mux creating these issues. But why sometimes.. The question is: what causes this, of course, and how and, maybe even most importantly, why?

Comment: It is hard to convince using filter to some arrogant civil eng. people. @Dave thats why I was digging to find the source.